# How to loop through all files in the current and sub directories to find a string?

Tags: files, directory, search

Hi I am trying to loop through a directory and all its subdirectories to find the string 'foo' in all the files, for example. I then want to display the file names (including full path) of all files which contain it.

The operating system is unix and using bash shell.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: On what operating system?

Comment: Ive added the info :)

Comment: Unix? Do you actually mean Unix or Linux? If Unix, which one? We need to know this to know what tools you have available. Do you have GNU `grep` (default on Linux) for example?

Comment: Its unix. using the command line. I do have the grep command too

Comment: What UNIX? AIX? Irix? Solaris? BSD? macOS? Do you maybe mean Linux and not Unix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a recursive `grep`. In GNU `grep`, at least, that's the `-R` option:

```
grep -R foo /path/to/parent/directory
```

If you use a full path, as above, for example `/home/callsign223/foo/` then all files will be shown with their qualified paths. And if you only want to see the file names, not the matching lines, you can use `-l` to only print the file name:

```
grep -lR foo /path/to/parent/directory
```

Note that the `-R` option is not portable and isn't supported by all `grep` implementations.

Answer (score 1):

if `grep -R` is not an option, then you could use `find` to run `grep` on each file:

```
find ./ -type f -exec grep -Hni "some-string" {} ';'
```

Comment: Why `-n` and `-i`? The OP doesn't indicate they want case insensitive matching or that they want the line numbers printed along with the matching line.

Comment: per @terdon, feel free to drop `-n` and `-i` as needed.

Comment: Note that the `some-string` string is actually treated as a regular expression, and that it would be treated as command line options if it started with a dash.  To counteract that, use `-F -e 'some-string'`.  This would search for it as a string and also coping with the case that the string start with a dash.

Comment: If you want to provide a standard-compiant answer, then drop the `-H` option and instead use `-exec grep ... /dev/null {} +`. When `grep` gets two or more filenames to search, it will always report the filename in which matches were found.  With `+` in place of `';'` at the end, you pass batches of names to the utility, instead of calling it once for each found name.

Answer (score 1):

Something that would work on all current Unix systems is to use `find` to find the files, and then `grep` to identify the files that contain the string `foo`:

```bsh
find . -type f -exec grep -l -F -e 'foo' {} +
```

The above command would find all regular files in or below the current directory.  For batches of found files, `grep` would be called to locate the string `foo`.  When locating the string in a file, `grep` outputs the file's pathname immediately and continues with the next file without reading further from the current file.

- We use `-l` to make `grep` stop and report the filename at the first line matching the given pattern.  This speeds processing up by ignoring the bit of the file after the first hit.
- We use `-F` to make `grep` consider the pattern a string rather than a regular expression. This potentially speeds processing up by not trying to de regular expression matches and allows us to match strings that look like regular expressions.
- We use `-e` with the given pattern, just in case it starts with a dash.  It doesn't do that in this instance, but replacing that static string `foo` with a variable would introduce the possibility of matching with a pattern that starts with a dash, which, therefore, would be mistaken for a command-line option.

---

A list of filenames is usually no good, though. You would likely want to do something to these files.  If so, you would do that as part of the utility that `find` executes through `-exec`:

```bsh
find . -type f -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        grep -q -F -e "foo" "$pathname" || continue
        # Do something with "$pathname" here
    done' sh {} +
```

Here we call a short in-line script to process found files in batches.  We check each file individually for the string `foo`, and ignore files that do not contain the string.  Where I added a comment in the in-line script, you would process the file referenced by `"$pathname"`.

You could also write the above with `find` executing `grep` separately before calling the in-line script:

```bsh
find . -type f -exec grep -q -F -e 'foo' {} \; -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        # Do something with "$pathname" here
    done' sh {} +
```

Note how the first `-exec` acts as a test on the current file before calling `sh -c` with the files that passed that test.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `ack` utility will do exactly what you are looking for. It may already be installed on your system. If not, then it can be downloaded from https://beyondgrep.com/.

One of the nice features of `ack` is that it ignores binary files by default and can be given command line options to restrict the types of files searched by some prescribed filter, or by file type (e.g. by programming language: `--type=cc` will search `.c`, `.h`, `.xs` files, `--type=awk` will search any files that match `/awk/` in the first line). These types can also be extended by the user on the command line or more permanently in the `~/.ackrc` file.