# Checking files for a string using a loop

Tags: bash, search

I'm trying to loop through files in a directory that start with the string stated in the `for` statement. Within the loop, I want to search for the pattern string `foo` within the file. If the string is found in the file I want to `echo` the `$filename`.

```bash
#!/ppp/bash

for filename in $(find ~/filesList -type f -name "pge_*")
do
      #If 'foo' located echo $filename
      
done
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to loop through all files in the current and sub directories to find a string?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/674267/how-to-loop-through-all-files-in-the-current-and-sub-directories-to-find-a-strin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First suggestion - there's no need to use `find` in your `for` loop, it slows things down. You can instead do something like:

```
for f in ~/filesList/pge_*
```

A rather important caveat is that this simplified version will not search subdirectories of `~/filesList` whereas the `find` version will, so depending on your actual use case you may not be able to simplify.

As for the search within those files, you'll want to use a `grep` type of construct:

```
if (grep needle haystack > /dev/null 2>&1)
then
  echo $f
fi
```

When `grep` finds the needle it's looking for, it returns a non-zero value, thus the condition evaluates to TRUE. I use the `> /dev/null 2>&1` to avoid seeing the results of the `grep`. If `grep` doesn't find the needle in the haystack, it's return code is 0, thus the conditional is FALSE, bypassing the `then` statement.

Comment: Thank you! To your first point, I do need to search subdirectories which is why I used 'find'. I'll implement your suggestion and report back!

Comment: I got it working with your suggestion :)

Comment: `grep` has a `-q` option that stops it form outputting anything.  It also does not complete the scan of the file after finding a matching line, making `grep -q` much faster than `grep >/dev/null`.

Comment: That's a silly way of doing what is essentially `grep -l`.

Answer (score 4):

Use `find` to execute `grep`:

```
find ~/filesList -type f -name 'pge_*' -exec grep -lF -- foo {} +
```

`-l` lists the names of files that contain a match for `foo`. `-F` means that the expression `foo` is to be taken as a fixed string rather than a regular expression.